# String argument error with dictionary commands

Tags: python, arrays, string, dictionary, arguments

I am trying to create a basic online store in python. But whenever I try to 'buy' an item it shows an error with my dictionary or something I am not sure.

The error: users[n]["Transactions"] = users[n]["Transactions"] + str(names_f, "bought", quanti, "of", final[choice*3], "with a total price of $"+price)
TypeError: str() takes at most 3 arguments (6 given)

```
    coun = 0

    users = [{"name":"Jack","username":"ja", "cc":'12345',"email":'whwhwwhh', "code": '111', "Transactions": ""}]

    def sign_in():
    username = input("Enter username")
    for i in range (len(users)):
            for x in users[i].values():
                if x == username:
                    pin = input("Enter pin")
                    if pin == users[i].get("code"):
                        print("Welcome", users[i].get("name"))
                        menu(username,users[i].get("name"))
                        break
                else:
                     print("Wrong pin")
                     sign_in()

     def menu (usern, names_f):
     global coun
     if coun == 0:
     order = ''
     total = 0
     for i in range (len(categories)):
            print(str(i+1)+".", categories[i])
            choice = int(input("Choose a category by typing the number beside the categories name."))-1
            print("Items in this list are")
            print("Itemname \t Price \t Stock")
            final = location[choice]
            for c in range((int(len(final)/3))):
                print(str(c+1)+'.',str(final[c*3]),"\t",'$'+str(final[c*3+1])), "\t", str(final[(c*3)+2])
            choice = int(input("Which item (Type number on left of the item name)"))-1
            while True:
                quanti = int(input("How many do you want to buy"))
                if quanti > final[choice*3+2]:
                    print("Sorry your request for", quanti, "Is more than we have at the store please try again")
                    continue
                else:
                    price = str(quanti*final[choice*3+1])
                    final[choice*3+2] = final[choice*3+2]-quanti
                    print("Thank you for your purchasing",quanti,"of", final[choice*3], "Your total price of this buy is", '$'+price)
                    for n in range (len(users)):
                        if usern == users[n].get("username"):
                            users[n]["Transactions"] = users[n]["Transactions"] + str(names_f, "bought", quanti, "of", final[choice*3], "with a total price of $"+price)
                            order += str(quanti, 'of', final[choice*3])
                            price += int(price)
                        done = input("Do you want to check out then type '1' if you want to continue type '2'")
                        if done == '1':
                            print("Thank you")
                            print ("Invoice:", order, "/n total price (HKD) $"+str(price))
                        else:
                            coun += 1
                            menu(usern,names_f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
variable_name = users[n]["Transactions"] + str(names_f) + "bought" + str(quanti) + "of" + str(final[choice*3]) + "with a total price of $"+ str(price)
users[n]["Transactions"] = variable_name
```

You will maybe need to declare variable_name somewhere.
Problem is that str usage is following 
str(object, encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
but whenever you pass comma it count it as another parameter. 
P.S. I'm not sure if you need all those str in my solution.

Comment: No need to declare `variable_name` beforehand, unless the key does not exist yet

Answer (score 0):

`str` is a class, and as stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) you can pass up to 3 parameters to it:

```
class str(object=b'', encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
```

Also, it also says what it does:

> Return a string version of object. If object is not provided, returns the empty string.

Meaning it is used to cast other types to string. Thus, you need to convert every int individually:

```
users[n]["Transactions"] = users[n]["Transactions"] + str(names_f) + " bought " + str(quanti) + " of " + str(final[choice*3]) + " with a total price of " + str(price)
```

Note the spaces before and after every string. Alternatively, you can format your string:

```
users[n]["Transactions"] = users[n]["Transactions"] + '%s bought %s of %s with a total price of %s' % (names_f, quanti, final[choice*3], price)
```

---

As a side note, it's worth checking what happens when the first transaction is made. If the key `Transactions` does not yet exist, you need to add an initial value before accessing it.

I usually do it like:

```
if key not in dict_:
  dict_[key] = 'my initial value'

dict_[key] += 'add my stuff'
```

another solution would be using the `get` method, which allows you to add a default value:

```
dict_.get(key, 'default')
```

Note that this will not add the key to the dictionary, meaning that trying to access its value later on will still result in a Key Error.